# Не получается вывести категории и посты к ним должным образом в wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые коллеги. Прошу помочь мне с выводом категорий и постов. Задача стоит в следующем: есть рубрика: "Диплом о высшем образовании", у которой есть подрубики - "Дипломы по году выпуска", "Дипломы по уровню образования" и т.д. К подрубрикам принадлежат посты, например, к подрубрике "Дипломы по году выпуска" - "2014-2018", "2012-2008".. А к подрубрике "Дипломы по уровню образования" - "специалист", "бакалавр"..  Вопрос такой: как можно вывести такую структуру: Рубрика(будет ссылка на статью) -> Подрубрика(без ссылки для наглядности) -> посты подрубрики. Приложу фото как должно быть [image: фото для примера]

Пробовал сделать, вывел сами Рубрики с постами подрубрик, а вот перед постами подрубрик ни как не могу вставить просто название Подрубрики

```
<?php 
                    $arg_cat = array(
                        'orderby'      => '',  //вывод рубрик
                        'child_of'     => '',
                        'parent'       => '',
                        'order'        => 'ASC',
                        'hide_empty'   => 0,
                        'exclude'      => '1',
                        'include'      => '',
                        'taxonomy'     => 'category',
                    );
                    $categories = get_categories( $arg_cat );
                ?>
                <ul class="left-sidebar_menu">
                    <?php
                        if( $categories ){
                            foreach( $categories as $cat ){?>
                    <div class="categories"><h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2></div>
                    <?php
                        $arg_posts =  array(  //вывод постов
                        'orderby'      => 'data',
                        'order'        => 'ASC',
                        'posts_per_page' => -1,
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                        'cat' => $cat->cat_ID,
                        );
                        $query = new WP_Query($arg_posts);
                    ?>  
                    <?php if ($query->have_posts() ) ?>
                    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
                    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata()?>
                </ul>
                <?php
                        }
                    }
        ?>
```

Буду очень признателен за помощь)

Answer (score 0):

После строки

```
<div class="categories"><h2><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h2></div>
```

вставьте

```
<div class="sub-categories"><h3><?php echo 'Подрубрики'; ?></h3></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вообще то, но хотелось бы чтобы динамически выводилась до постов подкатегория, типа '<h3><?php $sub_cats->name ?></h3>'. Как можно это сделать в цикле?